# Get an array of all files in a remote folder using SSH in BASH

Tags: arrays, bash, ssh, ls, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to get an array of all files in a remote folder using bash and SSH:

```bash
declare -a existing_files=$(ssh -q -i $SSH_KEY_PATH -t $PROXY_SERVER \
ssh -q -i ubuntu_vm $REMOTE_SERVER "ls $RAW_EEG_FOLDER")
```

but I only get the last filename. If I just run the command: `ssh -q -i $SSH_KEY_PATH -t $PROXY_SERVER ssh -q -i ubuntu_vm $REMOTE_SERVER "ls $RAW_EEG_FOLDER"` in a terminal window, it return all filenames but when I try to assign it to a variable, I only get. the last one. What am I missing?

## UPDATE:

I updated my code with Fravadona's answer to this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo $(bash --version)

source 'secrets/secrets.env'
declare -a existing_files;
readarray -t -d '' existing_files < <(
    ssh -q -i $SSH_KEY_PATH -t $PROXY_SERVER ssh -q -i ubuntu_vm $REMOTE_SERVER  "$(
        printf '%q ' find "$RAW_EEG_FOLDER" -mindpeth 1 -maxdepth 1 \
            '(' -type d -printf '%f/\0' ')' -o -printf '%f\0'
    )"
)
echo ${existing_files}
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
GNU bash, version 5.2.15(1)-release (aarch64-apple-darwin22.1.0)
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc. License GPLv3+:
GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html> This
is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it. There
is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

# The important bit here:
bash: -c: line 0: `find /home/.../ -mindpeth 1 -maxdepth 1 
( -type d -printf %f/\0 ) -o -printf %f\0'
```

Comment: Use an [array](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashSheet#Arrays) not [Command Substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

###### UPDATE

For bash < 4.3 (also added @CharlesDuffy suggestion)

```bash
#!/bin/bash

printf -v remote_cmd '%q ' find "$raw_egg_folder" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 \( -type d -printf '%f/\0' \) -o -printf '%f\0'

existing_files=()

while IFS='' read -r -d '' filename
do
    existing_files+=("$filename")
done < <(
    ssh ... "$remote_ubuntu_server"  "$remote_cmd"
)
```

---

###### OLD ANSWER

Maybe with:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

readarray -d '' existing_files < <(
    ssh ... "$remote_ubuntu_server"  "$(
        printf '%q ' find "$raw_egg_folder" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 \
            \( -type d -printf '%f/\0' \) -o -printf '%f\0'
    )"
)
```

**notes:**

- Requires bash >= 4.3 for `readarray -d`
- Doesn't work if the remote shell isn't bash **and** `$raw_egg_folder` contains control characters
- Bonus: the directories in `$raw_egg_folder`, if any, will have a `/` appended at the end.
- BTW, you should downcase your shell variables and double-quote any expansion

Comment: Thank you @Fravadona, can you explain what's going on there and format the answer correctly? I tried running your code but I'm running into all sorts of issue, bash is quite strict with formatting...

Comment: @FabioMagarelli, btw, be sure your shell _really is_ bash; this code will fail badly if run with `sh` instead. (Even on operating systems where `sh` is a symlink to `bash`, it runs in a compatibility mode with fewer features when started under the `sh` name).

Comment: @Fravadona, btw, personally, I'd reduce the number of command substitutions by one by using `printf -v rmt_cmd '%q ' ...` and then using `"$rmt_cmd"` when running ssh.

Comment: The shell on the remote server is bash, the one on my local is ZSH and I'm running a script saved as a `.sh` file. I'm not sure if that's what your asking in the comment :(

Comment: @FabioMagarelli, so, if you run `yourscript` or `/path/to/yourscript` or `bash yourscript` you're fine (but the former two are better than the last of those three options). If you run `sh yourscript`, you're not fine at all. And make sure that the script is actually executable (has `+x` file permissions) so the shebang will be honored. And BTW, I advise against using a `.sh` file extension; see the essay [commandname extensions considered harmful](https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/).

Comment: @FabioMagarelli, anyhow, if you show the error you have when using this code, either Fravadona or I should be able to puzzle it out. (Note that if you're on a Mac, you might want to change `#!/bin/bash` to `#!/usr/bin/env bash` to use a newer version of bash provided through Macports or Homebrew or Nix or so forth; the version provided by Apple is a 3.x release, and as this answer says, it needs 4.3 or newer).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy hang on, I got the `readarray` command not found error and I'm now upgrading bash to a newer version

Comment: @FabioMagarelli Don't fret, I'll update my answer for it to work with bash 3.2

Comment: I updated my question, I'm using bash 5 now but I'm getting a not very useful error :(

Comment: OK, now I think that I understand where the problem is: You're using an ssh command on the remote server, so, taken as it is you'll need to escape the command twice... Can't you use `ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh -q -i $SSH_KEY_PATH -W %h:%p $PROXY_SERVER" ssh -q -i ubuntu_vm "$REMOTE_SERVER" "$remote_cmd"` instead?

Answer (score 2):

This should be considered a comment on Fravadona's answer, illustrating the suggestion made in the comment at [Get an array of all files in a remote folder using SSH in BASH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75210916/get-an-array-of-all-files-in-a-remote-folder-using-ssh-in-bash/75211159?noredirect=1#comment132718390_75211159).

It (optionally) bumps the required version to 5.0 (if a short form shown below is used).

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# ^^^^^^^^^^^^- use bash as found from a PATH search, not the Apple version

# specify our find command as a string
find_cmd=(
  find "$raw_egg_folder" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1
    '(' -type d -printf '%f/\0' ')' -o -printf '%f\0'
)

### need to uncomment one of the two lines below
## bash 5.0 version
find_cmd_q=${find_cmd[*]@Q}
## bash 4.3 version
#printf -v find_cmd_q '%q ' "${find_cmd[@]}"

readarray -d '' existing_files < <(
    ssh ... "$remote_ubuntu_server" "$find_cmd_q"
)
```

Please do not accept this as an answer -- this is just an elaboration on a comment; Fravadona should get the credit.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using `declare -p`. It will also work if file names contain special chars:

```
eval $(ssh ..... $'bash -c \'existing_files=("'$RAW_EEG_FOLDER$'"/*); declare -p existing_files\'')
```

- `.....` the controlling stuff for ssh (copy of above).
- `bash -c ...` Ensures bash is running on the remote server.
- `$'xxx'` A C-Like string type of bash. Makes escaping easier.
- `existing_files=("'$RAW_EEG_FOLDER$'"/*)` create an array with all files.
- `declare -p existing_files` export the array as text.
- `eval $( ... )` Import the array to local shell variable. The import uses the same var name as the remote export.

Comment: after replacing the dots: `eval $(ssh -q -i $SSH_KEY_PATH -t $PROXY_SERVER ssh -q -i ubuntu_vm $REMOTE_SERVER $'bash -c \'existing_files =("'$RAW_EEG_FOLDER$'"/*); declare -p existing_files\'')` results in a syntax error: `upload_to_cerebro.sh: eval: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token ('
'bash: -c: line 0: bash -c existing_files =("/home/f.../"/*); declare -p existing_files'`

Comment: Cut&Paste error: There was 1 space to much between `existing_files` and `=`.

Answer (score 0):

All other answers had some syntax error but I reckon it is my fault as I'm not as good with Bash. I was able to solve my issue adapting a solution from a another question on Stackoverflow that I can't find anymore:

```bash
source 'secrets/secrets.env'

existing_files=()
while IFS=  read -r -d $'\0'; do
    existing_files+=("$REPLY")
done < <(ssh -q -i $SSH_KEY_PATH -t $PROXY_SERVER ssh -q -i ubuntu_vm \
$REMOTE_SERVER "find *.mat $RAW_EEG_FOLDER" -print0)
```

In this solution I also specified the type of file I wanted as otherwise the array of existing files would have included hidden files etc.

#### Note:

All_caps variables used are from my env (`source 'secrets/secrets.env'`) except for `$REPLY` which is just used to temporarily store the values of the array.